Obtain existence of an element without error
I try to query a particular UI, and when it does not exists, I get "Failed to get matching snapshots: Timed out while evaluating UI query." in the first line.
let account_number = applePayUI.buttons["Wallet.BankConnectAccountCredentialsView.AccountNumber"]
if account_number.exists {
    state = PAYMENT
} else {
    state = NO_PAYMENT
}

Is there a way to just test if the UI exists without getting an error?

I have a feeling something else is going on as you're using the exists property correctly.
Have you waited for your page to render/stabilize? You can test this by throwing a short sleep before the assignment.
How are you launching and referencing your application?
Are you able to access any UI elements at that time?
If you set a breakpoint at the line that is failing, can you print the app's debugDescription?
The waitForExistence function is hugely valuable. It might provide some stability for you at the cost of waiting for a timeout?
